# Will iTextSharp work with Bitmap objects not generated from a file?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, itext

I want to create and insert a lot of images into a PDF and iTextSharp looks promising for this. Their tutorial discusses adding a .net Bitmap object to the document, however, the Bitmap they use is one generated from an existing supported image file. Can iTextSharp take a Bitmap object that is directly generated by a graphics object?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll have to try them out before I see which is the right answer.

Comment: I have discovered that itextsharp does some "magic" by turning the Bitmap into a supported format for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the library uses either the Image or the Bitmap class, you can use in-memory bitmaps as well as ones which have been loaded from your hard disk (or wherever else) because .NET treats then uniformly.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it. In their tutorial they say getting image instance from byte array. You can save graphics object to memory stream and pass it to this method:

```
//public static Image getInstance(byte[] img)
Image img= Image.getInstance(imagebytes);
```

Here is the [tutorial](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch06.html).